# Keeping the array of application data in memory ( singleton class )?

Tags: ios, sqlite, singleton

I am using sqlite to store the array of data and I have more than one view controller in my application and my question is Is it right to create a singleton class to control that array of information coz I don't want to recreate the array from sqlite file every time loading a new view controller into the memory?

Comment: Of course. Why do you even ask?

Comment: Does each view really show exactly the same data?

Comment: @Wain yes they are. I asked this because I have not done like this before.I always load array while loading a new view controller into the memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A singleton will work. You can also just pass the array from the current view controller to the new view controller when it gets created and displayed.